# Restarting client gives exception in Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have one Hazelcast server and Hazelcast client but when I shutdown client and restart the client it is giving me below error:

```
Exception during initial connection to [localhost]:5701: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.net.SocketException: Address already in use: no further information to address localhost/127.0.0.1:5701
```

My Server code is below:

```
@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    try {

        Config config = new Config();
        
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701)
        .setPortAutoIncrement( true ).setPortCount(10);


        config.setClusterName("abc");
        config.setInstanceName("abc");
        MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig();
        mapConfig.setName("abc");
        config.addMapConfig(mapConfig);
        hazelCastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

        return hazelCastInstance;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and my client code is below:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.setClusterName("abc");
    clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("localhost");
    clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().setSmartRouting(true);
    clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addOutboundPortDefinition("5701-5720");
    
    ClientConnectionStrategyConfig connectionStrategyConfig = clientConfig.getConnectionStrategyConfig();
    ConnectionRetryConfig connectionRetryConfig = connectionStrategyConfig.getConnectionRetryConfig();
    connectionRetryConfig.setInitialBackoffMillis(1000)
                         .setMaxBackoffMillis(60000)
                         .setMultiplier(2)
                         .setClusterConnectTimeoutMillis(1000)
                         .setJitter(0.2);

    HazelcastClient hc = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

While shutting down client I am calling **hc.shutdown()**. But when restarting client it is giving me above error. Please help me to solve this issue.

Below in the logs for this that I am getting:

```
java.net.SocketException: Address already in use: no further information 

to address localhost/127.0.0.1:5701
18-Jun-2021 13:13:16.811 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.ClientConnectionManager.null hz.client_1 [APP] [4.2] Trying to connect to [localhost]:5703
18-Jun-2021 13:14:16.908 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.tcp.TcpClientConnection.null hz.client_1 [APP] [4.2] ClientConnection{alive=false, connectionId=1, channel=NioChannel{/127.0.0.1:5703->localhost/127.0.0.1:5703}, remoteAddress=null, lastReadTime=2021-06-18 13:13:16.897, lastWriteTime=2021-06-18 13:13:16.896, closedTime=2021-06-18 13:14:16.905, connected server version=null} closed. Reason: Failed to authenticate connection
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.newTimeoutException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:63)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:656)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.tcp.TcpClientConnectionManager.authenticateOnCluster(TcpClientConnectionManager.java:857)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.tcp.TcpClientConnectionManager.getOrConnectToAddress(TcpClientConnectionManager.java:594)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.tcp.TcpClientConnectionManager.lambda$doConnectToCandidateCluster$3(TcpClientConnectionManager.java:490)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.tcp.TcpClientConnectionManager.connect(TcpClientConnectionManager.java:444)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.tcp.TcpClientConnectionManager.doConnectToCandidateCluster(TcpClientConnectionManager.java:490)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.tcp.TcpClientConnectionManager.doConnectToCluster(TcpClientConnectionManager.java:406)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.tcp.TcpClientConnectionManager.connectToCluster(TcpClientConnectionManager.java:367)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.tcp.TcpClientConnectionManager.start(TcpClientConnectionManager.java:316)
        at com.hazelcast.client.impl.clientside.HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.start(HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.java:369)
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.constructHazelcastClient(HazelcastClient.java:460)
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClientInternal(HazelcastClient.java:416)
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClient.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1645)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1125)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18-Jun-2021 13:14:16.927 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.ClientConnectionManager.null hz.client_1 [APP] [4.2] Exception during initial connection to [localhost]:5703: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
18-Jun-2021 13:14:16.944 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.ClientConnectionManager.null hz.client_1 [APP] [4.2] Trying to connect to [localhost]:5702
18-Jun-2021 13:14:18.991 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.ClientConnectionManager.null hz.client_1 [APP] [4.2] Exception during initial connection to [localhost]:5702: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.net.SocketException: Connection refused: no further information to address localhost/127.0.0.1:5702
18-Jun-2021 13:14:18.993 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.ClientConnectionManager.null hz.client_1 [APP] [4.2] Unable to get live cluster connection, cluster connect timeout (1000 ms) is reached. Attempt 1.
18-Jun-2021 13:14:18.999 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.ClientConnectionManager.null hz.client_1 [APP] [4.2] Unable to connect to any address from the cluster with name: APP. The following addresses were tried: [[localhost]:5702, [localhost]:5703, [localhost]:5701]
18-Jun-2021 13:14:19.008 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService.null hz.client_1 [APP] [4.2] HazelcastClient 4.2 (20210324 - 405cfd1) is SHUTTING_DOWN
18-Jun-2021 13:14:19.024 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService.null hz.client_1 [APP] [4.2] HazelcastClient 4.2 (20210324 - 405cfd1) is SHUTDOWN
```

Comment: The server gets port 5701 (`.setPort(5701)`) and starts first. If you run on the same host the client will never be able to use 5701.  Try a different starting port for the client. It's possible also the ports are in ssome sort of WAIT state when your client restarts. More logs would help diagnose

Comment: @NeilStevenson, First time server and client both are getting started properly, but this expectation occurs when I restart the client so this cannot be issue of .setPort(5701) or am I wrong?, if I restart server also than it will work again, also I am using "ClientListener" to check if client getting disconnected or not and it is getting disconnected properly, and if we are calling client.shutdown() it should free all resources and ports associated to that client right?

Comment: If you run `shutdown()` the port will be released by the O/s but it may not happen immediately. Logs would help diagnose.

Comment: Anyway to release it completely on server shutdown?

Comment: Probably it isn't that. Logs are needed to help diagnose.

Comment: I have added logs, let me know if get something from, I am not getting issue from it.

Comment: That's just some of the logs. To help you'd need all logs for all processes from startup. If that's not going to be possible, how about a [reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following works as expected (no error). How is yours different ?

Server 1 starts and gets port 5701.
Client 1 starts and gets port 5702.
Client 1 stops.
Client 2 starts and gets port 5703.
Client 2 stops.
Server 2 stops.

For me, when client 1 closes, port 5702 is in `TIME_WAIT` status for a few seconds, so client 2 gets the next available port (5703).

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Config config = new Config();
        
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701)
        .setPortAutoIncrement( true ).setPortCount(10);

        config.setClusterName("abc");
        HazelcastInstance server = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
        
        System.out.println("SERVER UP");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5L);
        
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.setClusterName("abc");
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("localhost");
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().setSmartRouting(true);
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addOutboundPortDefinition("5701-5720");
        
        ClientConnectionStrategyConfig connectionStrategyConfig = clientConfig.getConnectionStrategyConfig();
        ConnectionRetryConfig connectionRetryConfig = connectionStrategyConfig.getConnectionRetryConfig();
        connectionRetryConfig.setInitialBackoffMillis(1000)
                             .setMaxBackoffMillis(60000)
                             .setMultiplier(2)
                             .setClusterConnectTimeoutMillis(1000)
                             .setJitter(0.2);

        HazelcastInstance client1 = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        
        System.out.println("CLIENT 1 UP");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5L);
        
        client1.shutdown();
        
        System.out.println("CLIENT 1 DOWN");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5L);
        
        HazelcastInstance client2 = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        
        System.out.println("CLIENT 2 UP");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5L);
        
        client2.shutdown();
        
        System.out.println("CLIENT 2 DOWN");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5L);
        
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1L);
        server.shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: Start only one server, then start client 1 and than start client 2, now after few minutes, try to stop client 1 and then stop client 2 also, after that again start client 1 and client 2 repeat this client 1 and 2 start stop few times error will get occurred, don't stop server, and if possible keep server and client in different project, "client 1 closes, port 5702 is in TIME_WAIT status for a few seconds" for how much time will it be in TIME_WAIT?

Comment: TIME_WAIT depends on your O/s, but it seems all that's wrong here is you're running out of ports.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying if I am shutting down the client it should free the port so for next it should be available. what is the best practice to do it?

Comment: Calling `shutdown()` on the Hazelcast instance is the best way. Hazelcast will close the port. When the O/s actually releases it depends on the O/s. It may be configurable at the O.s level, but it's rarely a good idea to change such settings.